# SQL to MapReduce - How to?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, etl

I have a complex query used in ETL process (SQL-based). It is too big to fit here but in general few inner joins between several tables and some BL using window functions and other 'goodies'.
I need to port it to Hadoop MapReduce. just dump all the tables in FROM cases to CSV format and bring files jto HDFS.
Then write MapReduce jobs that copy the logic implemented in SQL.

I wonder: **are there any best-practices/recommendations/pitfalls I should be aware of while porting SQL to MapReduce**?

Googling in my case was no good as the results were either too specific or some scientific papers with no practical tips.

Comment: You should really, **really** just check out [Hive](http://hive.apache.org) if you're already using SQL.

Comment: I really checked Hive and to me it feels like missing the point of Hadoop and MapReduce in my particular case.I am looking at Pig. You might want to check [this article](http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/hadoop/comparing-pig-latin-sql-constructing-data-processing-pipelines-444.html)

Comment: That's the point, you write SQL which gets compiled into MR. Pig is cool too, if you feel like that's better in your case.

Answer (score 2):

You can look at [sqoop](http://sqoop.apache.org/) as one of the option for transferring data between Hadoop and structured datastores.

Also, this link could be helpful- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/bd-sqltohadoop1/